# Obtain a list with the items found the minimum amount of times in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table where I have a certain id as a foreign key coming from another table. This id is not unique to this table so I can have many records holding the same id.
I need to find out which ids are seen the least amount of times in this table and pull up a list containing them.

For example, if I have 5 records with id=1, 3 records with id=2 and 3 records with id=3, I want to pull up only ids 2 & 3. However, the data in the table changes quite often so I don't know what that minimum value is going to be at any given moment. The task is quite trivial if I use two queries but I'm trying to do it with just one. Here's what I have:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = MIN(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY id)
```

If I substitute COUNT(*) = 3, then the results come up but using the query above gives me an error that MIN is not used properly. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a double `select` in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MIN(cnt) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM table GROUP BY id) t);
```

Answer (score 4):

I would try with:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY id ORDER BY COUNT(*) LIMIT 1);
```

This gets the minimum selecting the first row from the set of counts in ascendent order.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `GROUP BY` to produce a set of grouped values and additional select to get the `MIN` value from that group, only then you can match it against having

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 
 (SELECT MIN(X.CNT) AS M FROM(SELECT COUNT(*) CNT FROM table GROUP BY id) AS X)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `MIN()`  aggregate function is suposed to take a column, not a query. So, I see two ways to solve this:

- To properly write the subquery, or
- To use temp variables

First alternative:

```
select id
from yourTable
group by id
having count(id) = (
    select min(c) from (
        select count(*) as c from yourTable group by id
    ) as a
)
```

Second alternative:

```
set @minCount = (
    select min(c) from (
        select count(*) as c from yourTable group by id
    ) as a
);
select id
from yourTable
group by id
having count(*) = @minCount;
```